# How to make Bibtex works with a particular cls file?

Tags: bibtex, documentclass-writing

I am using a template that uses a particular class (proposal.cls). This class doesn´t support bibtex yet. I have noticed that in this class it wasn´t created thebibliography environment. I think this is the reason for the following error that I get when I run latex

> -! Latex Error: Environment thebibliography undefined.

So, I tried to fix this by inserting in my proposal.cls the code of article.cls below

```
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
 {\section*{\refname}%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
  \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
       {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
        \leftmargin\labelwidth
        \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
        \@openbib@code
        \usecounter{enumiv}%
        \let\p@enumiv\@empty
        \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
  \sloppy
  \clubpenalty4000
  \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
  \widowpenalty4000%
  \sfcode`\.\@m}
 {\def\@noitemerr
   {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist}
```

Unfortunately, it didn't help me... I still think that what I must do is to create the environment for thebibliography... I would like to insert the mininum code, only mandatory code... Any help?

Comment: Why don't you use `bibtex` or, better, `biber` and `biblatex`, and write a `.bib` data base?

Comment: @Bernard -- the `thebibliography` environment is defined in the document class, not in the translator (`bibtex` or `biblatex`), so that's necessary even with a `.bib` database.  (but using a `.bib` or equivalent database is still a very good idea.)

Comment: Maybe my question wasn´t so clear. But I do want to use an .bib file. I already have all refs in this file (database). I will use the refs of my last paper to prepare this document. Now I want to use a template that doesn´t support bibtex, I want to colaborate with the group that prepared this tex and class files! So others can be benefited too!!! :DThanks for your comments! @barbarabeeton what I need is to define thebibliography environment, can you help me? As you can see in my post I have already tried to solve the problem by creating newenvironment...

Comment: have you specified a `\bibliographystyle`?  i'm pretty sure that's necessary, as you have alluded to. try adding `\bibliographystyle{plain}` that would number the references.  if that succeeds (after processing the file once, running `bibtex`, and they reprocessing the main file two more times), then you can investigate what other bib styles are available, that might be more suitable.  also, in order to have references inserted, your document must include `\cite` instructions, or `\nocite{*}` to include the entire content of the `.bib` file.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks for your attention! I have already specified \bibliographystyle using apacite, plain and others, I have cited some refs and tried to use the \nocite option too. I used an .bib file that I already used in other work and I have tried to insert \bibitem directly in the tex file! Nothing worked... :(

Comment: is the class file `proposal.cls` by michael kohlhase?  that does have a mechanism for a biblatex bibliography, but it seems to be accessed by a `\printbibliography` command, not the "usual" `\bibliography` or `\begin{thebibliography}...\end{thebibliography}`.  if that's the class you're using, you should look at the documentation, although it's really rather limited on that topic.  there *is* an example file, `public.tex` that contains a small bibliography, so you might look at that as a model.

Comment: This cls file is really a brand new file created in my institution... The corret Name is proposta.cls. It is in portuguese (brazilian). I really need to define a newenvironment from the scratch...

Comment: Is there any news here? You are unclear about what exactly isn't working. Nobody has the original class and hence doesn't know what already is there. Without seeing the whole picture, it is more than difficult to finalize it.